# Laravel orm with() not works

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, orm

JoinSkipReason has not id, but JoinReview's primary key is foreign key of JoinSkipReason.

Query Builder works well...

I want to use with() to join the JoinSkipReason to the JoinReview table.

Thank you.

```
JoinReview::with(
    'join_skip_reason'
);
```

```
class JoinReview extends Model
{
    public function joinSkipReason()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Service\JoinSkipReason');
    }
}
```

```
class JoinSkipReason extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['join_review_id', 'reason'];

    public function joinReview()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Service\JoinReview', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: plz post the tables' structures.

Comment: @TsaiKoga Problem solved.

Comment: Good, it means you have primary_key. Laravel defaultly generate primary_key `id` for every table.

Comment: @TsaiKoga When I made `JoinSkipReason` table intentionaly excepted the `primary key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this issue myself, the issue is that for eager loading multi-word relations you should use camelCase.

In your code:

```php
JoinReview::with(
  'joinSkipReason'
);
```

I've also found a [(kinda old) issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3419) saying that you should also access the eager-loaded relation as camelCase, otherwise it will ignore the cached result and query the database again.

Comment: You save my life!

Answer (score 0):

> Check do like that

```
public function joinSkipReason()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Service\JoinSkipReason','join_review_id','id');
}
```

Comment: Sadly... It doesn't work. I think the problem because of the 'no primary key' in JoinSkipReason table...